# How to import a view in .install file?

Tags: 7, views, nodes, importing-exporting

I have an exported view code.How can I import it in .install file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. You implement `hook_views_default_views()` in yourmodule.views_default.inc and place the export there.

See [Using default views in your module](http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/api-default-views) for a detailed guide.